# How to change a matplotlib figure in a different cell in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am learning how to create and modify plots using matplotlib in Jupyter Notebook. I added the following magic function and import statements right at the beginning of the notebook:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Then, I created a cell and added all the following code:

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
y = x
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x[:2], y[:2], s=100, c='red', label='Red data')
plt.scatter(x[2:], y[2:], s = 100, c='blue', label='Blue data')
plt.xlabel('This is my x label')
plt.ylabel('This is my y label')
plt.title('This is my plot title')
```

The plot itself seems fine in this case, although I don't understand why the additional `Text(0.5, 1.0, 'This is my plot title')` line gets added, and nothing about the xlabel and ylabel text objects.
[image]

Now I find it rather impractical to always have to force every command pertaining to a plot into one cell. I would like to be able to create the basic plot in one cell and add labels and legend to it in a different cell (and later on do other manipulations on the plot, this is not a topic for this question though). To achieve this, I would need to reference the plot created in the first cell - for this, I used `plt.gcf()`.  However, when I run the following code, Python / matplotlib / Jupyter treats the different cells as different plots entirely. (Note: the dashed separations indicate different Jupyter Notebook cells.)

```
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x[:2], y[:2], s=100, c='red', label='Red data')
plt.scatter(x[2:], y[2:], s = 100, c='blue', label='Blue data')
#-------------------------------------------------------------
plt.gcf()
plt.xlabel('This is my x label')
plt.ylabel('This is my y label')
plt.title('This is my plot title')
#-------------------------------------------------------------
plt.gcf()
plt.legend(loc=4, frameon=False, title='Legend')
```

The output is as follows:
[image]

I tried changing `%matplotlib inline` to the apparently more modern `%matplotlib notebook` but it didn't help. I also tried removing the `plt.gcf()` rows from the beginning of the cells but I still got the same output.

**Edit**
My versions are:

- Python 3.7.0
- matplotlib 3.2.2
- ipykernel 5.2.1
- ipywidgets 7.5.1
- jupyter 1.0.0
- jupyter_core 4.6.3
- jupyter_client 6.1.6
- notebook 6.0.3
- Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Saving a figure to a variable like `fig` and then using `fig.gca()` to get the current axes** 
 (for additional plot commands) will do the trick.

Start by importing the packages and using the matplotlib inline environment:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
```

Then get your data and create a scatter plot for it (while saving the plot to a figure)

```py
# Generate some random data
x = np.arange(1,3)
y = x
x2 = np.arange(3,11)
y2 = x2
x3 = np.arange(11,21)
y3 = x3

# Create initial figure
fig = plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x, y, linewidth=5)
```

[image: Plot1] 
Then plot more data using the `fig.gca()` trick (the `fig` line shows the plot under the cell):

```py
fig.gca().scatter(x2, y2, color='r', linewidth=5)
fig
```

[image: Plot2] 
Add final data:

```py
fig.gca().scatter(x3, y3, color='g', linewidth=5)
fig
```

[image: Plot3] 
Add a legend:

```py
fig.legend(['Blue Data','Red Data','Green Data'], loc='lower right')
fig
```

[image: Plot4] 
Lastly, add x/y labels and title:

```py
fig.gca().set_xlabel('My x label')
fig.gca().set_ylabel('My y label')
fig.gca().set_title('A title')
fig
```

[image: Plot5]

**As you can see by my code, each addition to the plot (data, axis titles, etc.) was done in separate cells**

Comment: This has been immensely helpful, thank you very much @Jacob K!

Comment: I've just noticed though that these output plots are not interactive, despite having used the `%matplotlib notebook` magic on the top. There are no controls for zooming, no automatically updated plots etc. Basically, these plots (both yours and mine) seem to behave as they would under `%matplotlib inline`. Is my assumption correct? If yes, do you have any idea why interactivity doesn't work?

Comment: Hmm thats strange. Have you tried restarting the kernel? Also, I noticed that sometimes you have to run the import cell 2 times for the interactive plots to be enabled.

Comment: Also, if you really prioritize interactive plots, I highly recommend [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/)

Answer (score 1):

What you have will work if instead of having the first line as

```
%matplotlib inline
```

You use instead,

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

For example, see the discussion [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4879#issuecomment-128699102).  (And you'll need to restart the kernal to get this to take.)

Also, keep in mind that the pyplot interface is "[mainly](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.html) intended for interactive plots and simple cases of programmatic plot generation".

For building more complicated plots, like it seems you're doing, the OO interface is more powerful.  For example, with [the OO interface](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/agg_oo_sgskip.html) you can easily create two axes, set the title to each in one cell, and the labels for each in the next cell.  It's much easier to keep and handle on everything.

Comment: That's great info, I'll most probably dive into OO matplotlib! Thank you very much for the info, @tom10.

Comment: @lazarea: Any advantages to the pyplot interface are so small it's really not worth bothering to learn it. This `gca` and `gcf` stuff is usually a mess; instead save the figure and axes objects and use them as you need them (assign whatever else you need, like lines, etc). Honestly, I still use pyplot sometimes because that's the style I learned years ago and sometimes I start typing before I start thinking, but if I ever type gca or gcf it's usually the sign that I'm going in the wrong direction and I rework the start to not need them. If you're learning, I recommend avoiding it altogether.